# Using the verb "morire" in present tense to express the future

Tags: verbs, tenses

I have read the following sentence:

> Quando muoio tutto questo diventerà tuo
>   (instead of "quando morirò...").

I know that Italian often uses the present tense to express the future, but I am not sure whether it is usual do it here. Could someone confirm?

Comment: I always thought that present tense for a future was a bad translation from English, where you use present tense if it is an imminent future that is sure to happen.

Comment: @FedericoBonelli In English you would use the present tense in this sentence, but the reason is not because death is considered imminent. It's just a rule that "if" and "when" are followed by the present tense.